# Java - passing class with annotation to generic method

Tags: java, generics, annotations, raw-types, java-5

I'm working with JPA 2 and have the following method:

```
private static void wipeTable(EntityManager em, Class<? extends Table> klass) {
    String tableName = klass.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
    ...
}
```

I think there's a problem with the `Class<? extends Table>` parameter.  I have an entity class like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "collections")
public class Collection extends MyOtherClass implements Serializable { ... }
```

I can do `Collection.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name()` just fine, so I want to be able to pass `Collection` as a parameter.  Just calling `wipeTable(em, Collection.class);` has the following error, though:

> The method wipeTable(EntityManager, Class<? extends Table>) in the type FetchData is not applicable for the arguments (EntityManager, Class<Collection>)

I tried just having the parameter be `Class klass`, with no generics:

```
private static void wipeTable(EntityManager em, Class klass) {
    String tableName = ((Table)klass.getAnnotation(Table.class)).name();
```

This caused my IDE to suggest:

> Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized

I'm using Java 1.5.  Is there a way to say "give me a parameter of type `Class` that is annotated with `@Table`"?

Comment: can't you just use List<Table> in the method signature or some higher abstraction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but realize that Collection does not extend Table, it has a Table annotation on it. Change your signature to something like this:

```
private static <T> void wipeTable(EntityManager em, Class<T> klass)
```

As to your second point, there is no way when passing your Class parameter to place a restriction on it to have a particular annotation. But you **can** check for the presence of annotation in your method:

```
Table tableAnnotation = klass.getAnnotation(Table.class);
if(tableAnnotation != null) {
    // logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Since there's no way to restrict class parameters by annotation, is there any point to having `Class<T> klass` and not `Class klass`, other than to make the IDE not grumble?

Comment: That would be correct. Assuming you are doing no additional logic requiring knowledge of the generic type, then the generic parameter is only there to make the compiler happy.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need to introduce the type parameter to the method signature if you just use `Class<?>` as the parameter type.